# Search within dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I'm getting `NSDictionary` from **JSON** response

How can search within an `NSDictionary` of `Arrays`.Each array contains a `NSDictionary`. I want to search for particular casino name but i also want to get the address field with associated with it . How can i get it in swift ios.

The JSON response is below

```
{
    "success": [
        {
            "casino_id": "2",
            "casino_name": "cas",
            "address": "add",
            "distance": "0.19084827576745822"
        },
        {
            "casino_id": "4",
            "casino_name": "eeee",
            "address": "adressdd",
            "distance": "0.12319974564234398"
        }
    ]
}
```

code for searching iss below

```
var casinoarray = NSArray()  // CONTAINS THE JSON 
var resultsarray = NSArray() // USED FOR FILTERED ARRAY    
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self.casino_name == %@", searchText)

    resultsarray = casinoarray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
    tableView.reloadData()   
    print(resultsarray)
```

Please help me with it.

TIA

Comment: first of all you have to try to map this JSON using SwiftyJSON or ObjectMapper. Try it and then let us know

Comment: @UmairAfzal  I'm new to this could you please tell me what it means to map this json.

Comment: @UmairAfzal You can also map it manually. The desired result is to use objects and not dictionaries. There is no need for external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
        let prdicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self.casino_name contains[c] %@", searchText)

        let filterArray = self.yourArray.filter({
            prdicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
        })
        print(filterArray)
```

Comment: Thanks a million for suggesting this. I'm a newbie in using predicates.